# Sitemap re-submission for dynamic website

Tags: seo

I am very new to SEO and trying to explore it reading all day. I have finally created my dream carpooling site and working on the seo aspect now. I want do it on my own so I get to know about SEO better.Its is dynamic website. User post their trip details every day like given below ( IN quotes)

site : www.shareurride.com.au

sitemap: www.shareurride.com.au/sitemap.xml

Trip detail page :

> http://www.shareurride.com.au/ridedetails.php?id=MjY3&tripdate=MjAxMy0wNy0wNQ,,
>   http://www.shareurride.com.au/ridedetails.php?id=MTY2&tripdate=MjAxMy0wNy0wNQ,,

( trips like this will be added regularly everyday)

I have already have a program which dynamically insert this into my sitemap. 
My main question is , **is that I need to resubmit my site to GOOGLE every day** or will it do on its own. ?

Trip detail page is the only page will be dynamically added to sitemap. Please let me know . **If I need to resubmit the page regularly ,is there any tools to do that ?**

Thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO which is off-topic at Stack Overflow.


Comment: @JohnConde oh is it? ..  I'm sorry .I saw the SEO tag, so I posted it .Where can i post these questions to get expert reviews. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is that I need to resubmit my site to GOOGLE every day or will it do on its own. ?

No. Once Google knows where to find your sitemap they will continue to recrawl it periodically.